# How do I create apex tests with code that uses a custom label?

Tags: apex, unit-test, customlabel

I have code that uses the value of a custom label. I'd like to create a test for it, and I'd like to test for different values of the label. However I see no way to change or create labels in a test (or in Apex). Is it just not possible?

Comment: I've used a label in a test before, for example:
Boolean result = emailTst.HTMLBody.contains(System.Label.filterMask);

Are you receiving an error, or anything else that you can share?

Comment: There are no errors, the question is more on how I can change the value of the label. It's the 'code under test' that uses the label, so I'd like to set the label to a few different values to test the effects. I haven't found any way to set label values from apex though, so it might just not be possible.

Comment: In fact, I see now that's it's [documented](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/langCon_apex_SObjects.htm) that you can't create or change labels from 'normal' apex. I was hoping to find a workaround for test, like you can set the current pagereference, Test.runAs(user), HttpCalloutMock etc.

Comment: You might try using custom settings as a means of changing the values in a test environment or call a utility class that does it for you.

Comment: It's not possible. You should be using labels for translations, not one time static values. Custom settings would be more appropriate here, since that's what you're trying to test.